# A gridview for debugging collections?

Tags: c#, collections, visual-studio-debugging

I'm working with fairly large generic collections and I need a quick way to view all the items and their properties in these collections while debugging.

When I say view all the items, I mean I would like to view the collection as if it was bound to say.. a gridview. That way I could see all the item properties listed.

Currently VS2010 displays the collection object during debugging, but it takes several clicks before I can view any item's properties within the collection. 
As I'm using collection with 50 to 100 items in them, I've having a hard time getting a feel for the collection data because of having to click through to view each individual item's properties during debugging.

Do you have any ideas or know of a visual studio plugin that can help display collections in a table format or gridview format?

Thanks for you time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/ListVisualizer.aspx) debugger visualizer for lists and dictionaries on codeproject. It includes the source code, so you should be able to modify for your needs if not enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is a great [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163974.aspx) with varying examples on how to modify the way in which the data is displayed within the Visual Studio debugger.

Specifically I think you might want to take a more in depth look at [Visualizers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zayyhzts.aspx); note the *HOW TO's* on the left hand side and bottom.

Comment: Hi Aaron, thanks for the article links. Oded provided an answer a minute before you so I set he's response as the answer. Thanks for your time again.

Comment: @Llewellyn I believe Oded was 1 minute after mine but either way it is not a problem; hopefully the additional links help